# Bootstrap 4 hide and show grids

Tags: html, jsp, bootstrap-4

The objective it's to hide the red column on mobile and show it on higher resolutions but it just does not hide. Can somebody tell me what it's wrong with my code?, I pasted it in fiddle and works perfect but I take the same to my project and it does not work... What am I doing wrong? I'm using bootstrap 4.2.1

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5y8odg36/)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="d-none d-md-block col-md-8" style="background-color: red; height: 100vh">

                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4" style="background-color: black; height: 100vh">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Chrome test**(also proved on real phone with the same result)

[image: Chrome test]

[image: What browser shows me]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Into your `<head>`

> A  viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling. The width=device-width part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device). The initial-scale=1.0 part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser. 
>   (Source [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp))

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-12 bg-danger d-none d-lg-block"  style="height: 100vh">
      </div>
      <div className="col-12 col-md-12 bg-success d-lg-none"  style="height: 100vh">
      </div>
  </div>
```